# Promoted Links LIM action missing?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, promoted-links

I created a List Item Menu (LIM) custom action in Sharepoint Designer and I wonder where I will see that. I checked the Promoted Links list I created and changed the view to `All Promoted Links` (which now displays all links in table form) but I cannot see where the custom action is.

Comment: Found the answer but I cannot post the answer just yet. What I did is I edited the view and added the column `Title (linked to item with edit menu)`  instead of just `Title` to display the edit menu. The action is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the view and added the column `Title (linked to item with edit menu)`  instead of just `Title` to display the edit menu. The action is there.